# Including an animatied plot in animation

Tags: animation

I made my first animation using blender and now I want to include an animated plot graph in one corner of my initial animation such that a point on the graph moves with time to show the change of temperature. What do you think is the best way to achieve this? I was thinking of making several graphs with a point drawn on them on excel and then making a gif of this and adding it to the corner of the initial animation. Would this work and how? Are there better solutions?

Best wishes,
Nenko

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using the Blender video editor. 
You create the animation and render it to a sequence of images. Then create you animated graph and save it as a sequence of images.
In the video editor, you add the animation as an image sequence in one channel. Then in the next channel add the graphs as an image sequence. Use the editor settings for the graph to position and scale the graph.
When the video is rendered, the graph will be overlaid on the animation.

Comment: You could also add a new scene(+ at the top of the screen) and use the VSE to scale it to the corner of the output. I have done this many times to get overlays with animation.